# VS Code config, disable "editor.matchBrackets" for html tags

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
// Highlight matching brackets when one of them is selected.
"editor.matchBrackets": true,
```

It is possible to disable that setting for html tags ?

[image: html tags brackets highlight]

I know i can turn it off for a specific files like that

```
"[html]": {
      "editor.matchBrackets": false,
},

"[php]": {
      "editor.matchBrackets": false,
}
```

But then "editor.matchBrackets" will be disabled for "javascript" and "php" inside this files too.

Comment: While it's not exactly what you're asking for, it is possible to change the visual style of the bracket match highlighting, e.g., display a background color without the borders. If the reason you're asking is that the border box is making the cursor hard to distinguish in HTML especially, this might be a solution. The settings to change are these:

`"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
 "editorBracketMatch.background": "",
 "editorBracketMatch.border": ""
}`

Check out [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13379#issuecomment-302916286) for more info.

Comment: Thank you sir Magnus Lind Oxlund,"editorBracketMatch.border" made the trick, annoying borders are gone :)

Comment: I use a dark theme, so setting these to black fixed it for me, and effectively made those annoying borders around the brackets disappear.